# Iterate through multiple files displaying filename and first word in each

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to iterate through multiple files inside a directory and display filename and first word in file.

I am able to iterate through the files inside the directory and display the files names.

```
@echo off
set SetupDir=D:\docs
for /r "%SetupDir%" %%f in (*.*) do echo %%f
pause
```

Comment: Are we to assume that every file within `D:\docs` is a text file? Instead of simply using `echo`, you may find it easier to also nest another [tag:for-loop].

Comment: folder contains text files only

Comment: I note that you've used a recursive command, is your intention to retrieve the first word of the first line of every file in the `D:\docs` directory, _as mentioned in your question_? or to also perform the same task for each file within each of its sub-directories?

Comment: If Powershell is an option, you could use something like this `gci *.txt | %{[PSCustomObject]@{filename = $_.fullname; word = ((gc $_ -ReadCount 1 -TotalCount 1) -replace '(^\w+).*', '$1')}}`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks..but one problem..for the first word "0001-TO-025251" it is giving output as "0001".. My aim is to get the word up to the space..

Comment: You can replace `(^\w+).*` with `(^\S+).*`

Comment: Something like this: `gci *.txt | %{[PSCustomObject]@{filename = $_.fullname; word = ((gc $_ -re 1 -to 1) -replace '(^\S+).*', '$1')}}`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, the task can be easily performed using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

You could still do that from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'D:\docs' -Filt '*.txt' -Rec|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{(GC -Li $_.FullName -To 1).Split(' ')[0]+' '+$_.FullName}"
```

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```dos
PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'D:\docs' -Filt '*.txt' -Rec|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|%{(GC -Li $_.FullName -To 1).Split(' ')[0]+' '+$_.FullName}"
```

And in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```ps1
GCI 'D:\docs' -Filt '*.txt' -Rec|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|%{(GC -Li $_.FullName -To 1).Split(' ')[0]+' '+$_.FullName}
```

---

If you're using a minimum of [powershell-3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-3.0) it could be refined further.

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'D:\docs' -File -Filt '*.txt' -Rec|%%{(GC -Li $_.FullName -To 1).Split(' ')[0]+' '+$_.FullName}"
```

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```dos
PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'D:\docs' -File -Filt '*.txt' -Rec|%{(GC -Li $_.FullName -To 1).Split(' ')[0]+' '+$_.FullName}"
```

In [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```ps1
GCI 'D:\docs' -File -Filt '*.txt' -Rec|%{(GC -Li $_.FullName -To 1).Split(' ')[0]+' '+$_.FullName}
```

If you're not interested in the contents of any of the subdirectories, all you need to do is remove `-Rec`, *(`-Recurse`)*, from whichever example you've chosen from above.